# How to hide post, but show featured image for image slider in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, hide, nivo-slider

Is there a way to add a post with a featured image, and prevent the Post Title and Post Body from showing in the blog?  I tried making the post "private", but that hides both the Post Title and the featured image.

Or a way to not post a certain category as a post, but allow the featured image in that category?

Comment: I don't thinbk I understood it fully. Can you give us some context?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom template with a loop that only grabs the template tag info for the image without the other content that you don't want displayed.

Do you want this mixed in to a feed with regular posts or just as it's own feed?

Comment: Exclude from feed also.  Any link that would guide me on the scripting required for creating this loop?